# Do not display 0's in workbook xlsxwriter

Tags: xlsxwriter

There is a way to have a workbook not display 0 values under Excel->Preferences (on mac).  Is there a way to set this with xlsxwriter?  I know I can do this via conditional formatting for each sheet, but it involves setting the font to be an invisible color and my background colors are variable, so that's a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [worksheet.hide_zero()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-hide-zero) method, like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hide_zero.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.hide_zero()

worksheet.write('A1', 1)
worksheet.write('A2', 0)
worksheet.write('A3', 1)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]